# BlackBerry: how to override makeMenu() and cancel (so that no menu appears at all)?

Tags: blackberry

In my screen class, I can override `makeMenu` and use it to do something, like this:

```
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance) {
   reDraw();
}
```

However, when I click the trackball `reDraw();` is called (like I want), but then a menu still pops up (with `Call Voice Mail` and `Switch Application` options).

How can I cancel this menu entirely here?  I want to use the click of the trackwheel purely as a simple click event, without a menu popping up.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by not overriding `makeMenu`:

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    reDraw();
    return true;
}
```